# Identify IDs with multiple products in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to identify IDs with multiple products in Excel. For example, I want to put Y (or highlight etc) next to ID 1 since it has 3 different products listed. How can I do that?

```
ID    Product
1      A
1      C
1      D
2      B
2      B
```

Comment: Does ID 2 qualify? It has two products listed, but they are both the same.

Answer (score 1):

With the worksheet set up like this:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Put this formula in `C2` and fill down:

```dart
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,A2)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,A2,$B:$B,B2),"Y","-")
```

Note that if you use it for conditional formatting, no helper columns are required.

**Explanation:**

The formula works by counting the number of times the combination of the current `ID` **and** the current `Product` appears in the data (using the `COUNTIFS()` function). It then compares this to the number of times the `ID` appears, irrespective of the `Product` (using the `COUNTIF()` function). If the counts don't match, that means there is at least one `ID` matching the current one elsewhere in the data linked to a different `Product`.

Comment: It's a very clever answer, but it has taken me a long time to understand how it works (mostly bfrom lack of knowledge about `COUNTIFS()`). It would be helpful if you expanded your answer with an explanation of the mechanism behind the formula.

Comment: @AFH Yeah, I was wondering whether I should explain it or not, as it's very simple for me and other users should be able to figure out how it works by reading up on the `COUNTIFS()` function. I might just add a quick explanation. PS Done.

Answer (score -1):

The following formula checks for multiple entries in column `A`:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,A2)>1
```

This can be checked in a separate column:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,A2)>1,"Y","")
```

Or it can be used in a conditional format.

This assumes that the presence of multiple ID entries counts as products that differ in some way, even if the product code is the same.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is after. (WRT you last sentence.)

Comment: @robinCTS - The questioner didn't answer, so I assumed what was easiest to code. Sorry that my answer crossed with yours.

Comment: That's OK. I'm not worried about that. It's just that if it was a case of detecting multiple IDs, there is no need to show the products and the question would be "How do I detect and flag duplicate IDs". I was just trying to alert you that it's extremely unlikely (though not impossible ;-) ) that your interpretation is correct.